# no request header origin when using expo to express server

Tags: express, react-native, expo

I'm learning React Native and I'm testing it on my phone with expo and I'm trying to call a an api remotely which has been working perfectly with my react bundle on a web server as well as on localhost.

my app.js

```
var allowedOrigins = ['http:// localhost:3000', 'http:// site.com'];

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    const origin = req.headers.origin;
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1){
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    }
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorizati$
    next();
});
```

the issue is that there's no origin in the req headers when I try calling the api from the app.

App.js (React native)

```
class User extends React.Component {
    render() {

        fetch(`https://api.site.com/user`)
        .then((response) => { console.log('response', response) })
        .catch((data) => console.log('data', data))

        return null
    }
}
```

the req.headers while accessing from expo looks like

```
{ connection: 'upgrade',
  host: 'api.site.com',
  'if-none-match': 'W/"19f-pkIEHBJ9V3GhwsEXhmyI2oBhsbo"',
  accept: '*/*',
  'user-agent': 'Expo/2.6.7.1015752 CFNetwork/889.9 Darwin/17.2.0',
  'accept-language': 'en-us',
  'accept-encoding': 'br, gzip, deflate' }
```

am I missing a step somewhere between learning react for web and react native for apps?

Answer (score 4):

[Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) is the URL of the website where the request was made from, hence it's not applicable to mobile apps.

There's no need to set [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) headers for mobile apps as only browsers restrict cross-origin requests.

If your mobile app is not able to make requests to the server, the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: the backend currently is there to work with localhost and the domain, then are you suggesting I create another backend service just for mobile without cors?

Comment: cause if I use *, then it breaks the actions that require credentials on the web version

Comment: Just leave it as it is. Are you getting any request errors for your mobile app?

Comment: no errors on the app itself, but the issue is that the backend needs an origin for it to respond to api calls

Comment: Why does your backend need an origin for it to respond to api calls?

Comment: to keep it secure and limited to certain domains, otherwise anyone can flood the server with api requests? is that not the standard?

Comment: Yeah your code currently prevents other websites from directly querying your endpoints (though people can still flood it through proxying or directly with `curl` etc), but mobile apps have neither domains nor restrict cross-origin policies, so how are you going to restrict other mobile apps from using your endpoint?

Comment: Ideally the React Native code would work both on native and expo web. So some provision for CORS is worthwhile.